# Telegram bot api Рассылка

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Написал команду для рассылки, но она почему-то отправляется только 1 человеку.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["Newsletter"])
def answer(message):
    if (message.from_user.id == 365156441):
        newsletter = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        cursor.execute("SELECT `id` FROM `Users_mining`")
        allusers = cursor.fetchall()
        for i in range(len(allusers)):
            time.sleep(5)
            bot.send_message(allusers[i]['id'], newsletter )
```

Тестировал на боте где в бд не много пользователей, там работает, но там где их много почему-то не работает.

Comment: Что такое "не работает"?

Comment: Для тестирования отправлял сам себе сообщение "Успешно"(В цикле), но "Успешно" отправлялось мне только 1 раз.
Цикл выглядел так:
            for i in range(len(allusers)):
                time.sleep(5)
                bot.send_message(allusers[i]['id'], newsletter )
                time.sleep(1)
                bot.send_message(365156441, "Успешно!")

Comment: Все еще ничего непонятно, что у вас в бд лежит?

Comment: Если не понимаете мой код, то можете пожалуйста написать с нуля?
id для отправки можно достать через команду `cursor.execute("SELECT `id` FROM `Users_mining`")`  и чтобы рассылку мог отправлять только я.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что бот не мог отправить сообщение тем кто заблокировал его, в итоге он просто выходил из цикла. 
Исправил это так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["Newsletter"])
def answer(message):
    if (message.from_user.id == 365156441):
        newsletter = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        cursor.execute("SELECT `id` FROM `Users_mining`")
        allusers = cursor.fetchall()
        for i in range(len(allusers)):
            try:
                time.sleep(5)
                bot.send_message(allusers[i]['id'], newsletter )
            except:
                continue
```

Чтобы рассылка быстрее отправлялась можно сделать чтобы пауза делалась каждый 20 раз(можно и 30):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["Newsletter"])
def answer(message):
    if (message.from_user.id == 365156441):
        newsletter = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        cursor.execute("SELECT `id` FROM `Users_mining`")
        allusers = cursor.fetchall()
        for i in range(len(allusers)):
            try:
                if i % 20 == 0:
                    time.sleep(1)
                bot.send_message(allusers[i]['id'], newsletter )
            except:
                continue
```

Comment: а как сделать чтобы значение чат айди тянуло с какого-то масива\файла?

Comment: Вам не нужно переменной `i` для цикла — это не Питонскый подход. Лучше сделать так: `for user in allusers: ..... bot.send_message(user['id'], newsletter)`

Comment: Когда вам — во втором примере кода — нужно `i`, начинайте цикл так: `for i, user in enumerate(allusers):`

Comment: А что делать если нужно через register_next_step_handler получить текст рассылки и пользователю нужно сделать рассылку изображений с текстами?